# cv2 module capturing frame from video every 5 seconds

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I have been trying to capture a frame(screenshot) after every 5 seconds from a live `.webm` video stream which is constantly increasing in duration.

```
import cv2
import time


TIMER = int(5)
k=0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.webm')
capture=int(1)

while True:

    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('a', img)

    if ret:

            prev = time.time()
            while TIMER >= 0:
                ret, img = cap.read()

                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                cv2.putText(img, str(TIMER),
                            (200, 250), font,
                            7, (0, 255, 255),
                            4, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.imshow('a', img)
                cv2.waitKey(125)


                cur = time.time()


                if cur-prev >= 1:
                    prev = cur
                    TIMER = TIMER-1
                    if TIMER == 0:
                        ret, img = cap.read()
                        cv2.imshow('a', img)
                        cv2.waitKey(2000)
                        cv2.imwrite('camera' + str(capture) + '.jpg', img)
                        capture=capture+1
                        TIMER = int(5)




    else:
        break


cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here my code captures the frame after every 5 frames, I'm not able to figure out the framerate calculation and making it work to capture frames after every **5 seconds** rather than **5 frames**.

Comment: It worked for me. Capture before every  5 seconds, then after 5 seconds. I changed cv2.waitKey(1) instead of 2000

Answer (score 1):

If you want to utilize the fps information of the video an approach might be:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'path/to/vid')
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
save_interval = 5

frame_count = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame_count += 1

        if frame_count % (fps * save_interval) == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(r'path/to/save/to')
            # optional 
            frame_count = 0

    # Break the loop
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```